# How to set social icons and text one by one?

Tags: html, css

Here is my jsfiddle link: http://s30.postimg.org/44jynnz35/Untitled_2.png

Now it shows like this http://s30.postimg.org/44jynnz35/Untitled_2.png

I need vertically align one-by-one.

```
<div id="social-bar">
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Open-Source-Hacker/181710458567630">
                    <i class="icon icon-facebook"></i>
                    <span>Facebook</span>
                </a>
                <a href="https://twitter.com/moo9000">
                    <i class="icon icon-twitter"></i>
                    <span>Twitter</span>
                </a>
                <a href="https://plus.google.com/103323677227728078543/">
                    <i class="icon icon-google-plus"></i>
                    <span>Google Plus</span>
                </a>
                <a href="http://opensourcehacker.com/">
                    <i class="icon icon-rss"></i>
                    <span>Blog</span>
                </a>
            </div>
```

May i know, What is the exact css property to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You given wrong JSFiddle link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anchors are, by default, inline. Use this in your CSS:

```
#social-bar a {
display:block;
}
```

Comment: is there possible to get mail box icon ,like this same.?

Comment: you'd have to search google for that. there are many icon sets out there that are free.

Comment: is there possible to get mail box icon ,like this same.? @leftside:

Comment: you'd have to search google for that. there are many icon sets out there that are free.

Comment: yes.. but i need the same width and height as above my other icon.

Comment: I understand, but I have no idea what icons you used or where you got them. just do a google search for social media icon sets. You will find plenty that come as sets.